# Prepare shower for tiling

Tags: shower, tile

I got guys doing some tiling and this is what it looks like before the tile.
How would you quality this work? [image]

Comment: He's going to put on another coat of Redgard  right??

Comment: If the mesh tape doesn't have a backing, those corners won't be waterproof.

Comment: I would not have anything good to say about what I see.

Comment: Without a continuous membrane all you're getting is crack isolation, not waterproofing. Houses settle: it *will* crack someday. When it does I'd prefer it'd be WP.... Tile over that and you'd be ineligible for, e.g., CBP's lifetime warranty because you skipped too many steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prepare shower for tiling

This is not prepared for use in a shower. The seams of cement backer-board should be filled with mortar prior to application of the mesh tape. Also, it is not waterproof yet because it needs at least one more coat of waterproofing.

You had better take a good look at the pan; how it was constructed and prepared. A bad pan will make for a really bad day for you sometime in the (perhaps near) future...

Comment: +1. They did steps 1, 2, and 5 : backer board, tape, and the field application of 'red'. They did not do 3 and 4 : 'mud' the tape and cut-in the corners with 'red' using a brush.

Comment: The one coat of Redgard is not even a full coat, it looked like a half hearted attempt at .....something....